# How to access child accounts inside a user account in android with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making a project where I can register 'Users' in my firebase database then register their 'baby' as well. The child key from the 'baby' node is the babyid for each baby inserted. How can I make something like a session for each babyid like whenever the user switches to another baby account, I can access the baby's data all throughout the app and modify everything inside of that specific babyid only. I'm new to firebase, pls help.

[This is the JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmrau.png)

Comment: Please be more specific to what you're asking, and even better, add some examples to show what exactly do you want to do. Also please respond with @

Comment: @PradyumanDixit, sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to access a specific babyid so I can insert/delete/modify the data inside of it.

Comment: What data do you have to identify the specific baby id, which distinguishes it from all others?

Comment: All baby ids have the same nodes so none... I just want to access the name,bday,gender and img_path nodes for each babyid... like how do I get the babyid's reference? and how do I add another child inside the babyid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the push id of each baby inside the babyids while inserting data like below:

```
-Users
 -Uid
  -baby
   -pushIdForBaby1
     -pushIdForBaby1
     -baby_bday
     -baby_name
     -img_path....
```

Fetch the User data in POJO and you can get that users baby data with there pushIds.

Comment: how do I get its reference using java? I can only retrieve usersid but I don't know how for pushedIdForBaby1

Comment: oh I think I get it. I'll try it first then I'll get back to you

Comment: the idea worked! Big thanks~!